# Android: measureText() Return Pixels Based on Scaled Pixels

Tags: android, paint, text-size

So I use Paint's measureText() method to measure the width of a segment of text, but I wanted to measure text based on a certain text size. Say I wanted to get the width of a text segment that will be 20 scaled pixels when it occupies a certain TextView. I tried the following:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(20);
paint.measureText("sample text");
```

However, it does not seem to be working. I believe it is returning a width with respect to a smaller text size. I feel like I'm missing something that will make me slap myself in the face and yell herp derp.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to get the densityMultiplier like so:

```
final float densityMultiplier = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
final float scaledPx = 20 * densityMultiplier;
paint.setTextSize(scaledPx);
final float size = paint.measureText("sample text");
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was under the impression that setTextSize's parameter was in scaled pixels already, so I was confused with where I was going wrong. Works fine now. :-)

Comment: not working for me, I have the textview set to 20sp and running this code the size gives me something smaller than expected

Comment: Check your font size preference: sp
Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and the user's preference.

Comment: You could try checking your theme or style settings. Try doing this on a different phone. Try applying the above code in a fresh project setup just for this. Something non-standard is causing this and it's up to you to figure it out.

Comment: @schwiz have you ever figured this out? I am facing a similar problem ... I measure the text, and then try to set the width of a TextView accordingly, but I have to multiply the result from mearueText by density.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this when I have to.

```
int textSize = 20;
for(int i = 2; i<18 && curTextSize< textSize;i+=2)
{
    this.label.setTextSize(i);
    curTextSize = this.label.getPaint().measureText(this.label.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on answers but in reference to the comments by @schwiz and @AndreasEK on the accepted answer:

`measureText()`, along with `getTextBounds()`, does not include padding so it's possible that the solution to their problem is to add the left and right padding (or start and end padding)

```
final float scaleFactor = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
final float scaledPx = 20 * scaleFactor;
paint.setTextSize(scaledPx);
final float padding = scaleFactor * (textView.getPaddingStart() + textView.getPaddingEnd());
final float size = paint.measureText("sample text") + padding;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Paint.SetLinearText(true)
```

That solved the problem for me.