# Is possible to develop a fill-the-gaps exercise in Android?

Tags: android, string, dynamic, textview, android-edittext

Is it possible to develop something like this in Android?:

[image]

Note that the length of any of the three text components is dynamic.

I pretend to receive a first String (that might be multilined) then an input field for the user, and finally, another String (can also be multilined). I want them all to seem like they belong to the same sentence.
I'm not asking for the full code, just some clues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can format this in the HTML

Comment: im not asking for formatting the red color. It is about placing all components chained, one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieve it by using FrameLayouts and with the help of this posts:

- [Android: measureText() Return Pixels Based on Scaled Pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232541/android-measuretext-return-pixels-based-on-scaled-pixels)
- [Get current visible text in textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636946/get-current-visible-text-in-textview)
- [How to find android TextView number of characters per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970640/how-to-find-android-textview-number-of-characters-per-line)

Comment: Hi, could you provide some example?