# getTextBounds returning wrong values

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the width in pixels of a text string I'm getting a value of 8, which does not make ence since that would mean each letter is 1 pixel whide. 
I have the following code

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(12);
paint.getTextBounds("ABCDEFGHI", 0, 1, bounds);
width=bounds.right;      // this value is 8
```

bounds has the values of 0,0,8,9

Comment: give a try to paint.measureText if you only need the width. That's what I do since I found getTextBounds had some inaccuracies.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method takes the following parameters:

```
getTextBounds(char[] text, int index, int count, Rect bounds)
```

And you request the width of only one character (the third parameter), not the whole string:

```
paint.getTextBounds("ABCDEFGHI", 0, 1, bounds);
```

`bounds.right` is 8, which is the width of the letter `A`.

The correct call in your case would be:

```
String str = "ABCDEFGHI";
paint.getTextBounds(str, 0, str.length(), bounds);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the following code to get the width (in pixels) for your text (found from [Android: measureText() Return Pixels Based on Scaled Pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232541/android-measuretext-return-pixels-based-on-scaled-pixels)):

```
final float densityMultiplier = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
final float scaledPx = 12 * densityMultiplier;
paint.setTextSize(scaledPx);
final float size = paint.measureText("ABCDEFGHI");
```

size should be your width in pixels.